# How can we improve the following sentence?

Tags: graph-theory, article-writing

How can we improve the following sentence?

> Let $G$ be a planar graph **with** $n$ vertices **with** minimum
> degree $5$ with diameter two where $n$ is odd.

Firstly, I realized that I used "with" three in a row, so I made a modification by changing one of them to "of".

> Let $G$ be a planar graph **with** $n$ vertices **of** minimum
> degree $5$ with diameter two where $n$ is odd.

However, I still believe that there's room for improvement such as  the sentence is too long and feels quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It often helps to break up sentences.  Also, in this particular case, the sentence is ambiguous because you've separated the definition of $n$ from a qualification about $n$.  Are you saying that $G$ has an odd number of vertices and all of them have degree at least $5$?  Or are you saying that $G$ can have any number of vertices but that an odd number of them have degree at least $5$?

Assuming the former meaning is intended, I'd write it like this:

Let $G$ be a planar graph with an odd number of vertices, $n$, and diameter $2$.  Assume each vertex has degree at least $5$.

If the latter meaning is intended, I'd write it like this:

Let $G$ be a planar graph of diameter $2$.  Assume that an odd number, $n$, of the vertices of $G$ have degree at least $5$.

Comment: Nice suggestion.

Comment: Regarding the first suggestion: I think "..with *an odd number, n, of vertices* and diameter 2.." seems more grammatical, however I agree that your suggestion does sound a little more natural.