# Is the term "n-order graph" commonly used?

Tags: graph-theory, article-writing

*Order* of a graph is the number of vertices in the graph.  I don't know if  "n-order graph" is common or standard. For example,

> We obtain a **25-order** graph with minimum degree 5.

I'm aware that the following statement might also be common.

- We obtain a graph **of order 25** with minimum degree 5.
- We obtain a graph **on 25 vertices** with minimum degree 5.

But just as mentioned in the recent [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758045/how-can-we-improve-the-following-sentence/4758062#4758062), the above two expressions could lead to misunderstanding, as it might be interpreted as the graph having 25 vertices with degree 5.

Perhaps the following expression is more common.

- We obtain a **25-vertex** graph with minimum degree 5.

However, I still want to ask whether "25-order" is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not commonly used.

I have never seen it used personally, but that doesn't seem like a sufficient answer, so let me try to add more.

First, I looked through electronic copies of West's *Introduction to Graph Theory* and Diestel's *Graph Theory*. Both of these commonly use "graph of order $n$" and its cousins "component of order $n$", "clique of order $n$", "tree of order $n$" where appropriate. If they ever used a variant of "$n$-order" as an adjective, you would expect a search to find the string `order graph` or `order component` or `order clique` or `order tree` to find them, and they did not.

I would not suggest using it, for several reasons:

- The phrase "$n$-order graph" looks like it might also mean something else related to finding orderings of something related to the graph. For example, a false positive I found in West's textbook was a citation of D.R. Woodall's paper "Cyclic-order graphs and Zarankiewicz's crossing-number conjecture" and that is what "$n$-order" feels like.
- The words "order" and "size" are fairly established terminology for the number of vertices and the number of edges, but they're also *bad* terminology; the distinction is completely opaque to someone unfamiliar with the terms, because it's in no way guessable. Personally, I try to use them correctly when I have to, but also try to make it clear from context what they mean.
- The alternative "$n$-vertex graph" is both clearer *and* is commmonly used.

I also do not think that "graph on $25$ vertices with minimum degree $5$" is ambiguous upon reflection - "minimum degree $5$" cannot refer to a vertex, only to a graph. But maybe it is better to avoid it anyway, because "$25$-vertex graph with minimum degree $5$" is also clear, and does not take any thought to realize it is unambiguous.

---

Part of the issue is just that the word order is ungrammatical: just like "$25$-vertex graph" refers to a graph with $25$ vertices, "$25$-order graph" would refer to a graph with $25$ orders. The correct way to turn "of order $25$" into an adjective is to say "order-$25$ graph".

This is still not used in the textbooks I checked, and it feels somewhat less formal to me, but one can find papers referring to either "order-$n$ graphs" or "order $n$ graphs" (the hyphen varies).

Comment: Nice! I have another question: can "odd order graph" be used? While I did look up Bondy's book and found that most instances use "of odd order," some literature also used "odd order graph." For instance: [https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(02)00810-5]: "Here we look in particular at odd order graphs G with low deficiency and high maximum degree relative to the order."  (specially when additional suffixes are after graphs )

Comment: I was looking at that one in my search, because I also thought it was more likely; the textbooks I checked do not use it, and only say "graphs of odd order". I think that "odd order graph" is more acceptable, for two reasons: (1) "odd" is an adjective describing the order, unlike "25" (2) we cannot write "odd-vertex graph" as an alternative. But I would avoid it if there's an alternative that flows well.

Comment: (Also, under some circumstances, you can talk about $(2k+1)$-vertex graphs, but it's not really a synonym.)